# wp_create_category deprecated?

Tags: functions, deprecation

Was trying to use this today:

**WP Create Category**
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_category

Trying that (which I also assume it's only going to add terms to the built in "Categories" taxonomy) throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_create_category() in /yourwebsite/wp-content/themes/fitt/functions.php on line 123
```

Though I do see it in /wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php on line 45:

```
/**
 * Add a new category to the database if it does not already exist.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @param int|string $cat_name
 * @param int        $parent
 * @return int|WP_Error
 */
function wp_create_category( $cat_name, $parent = 0 ) {
    if ( $id = category_exists($cat_name, $parent) )
        return $id;

    return wp_insert_category( array('cat_name' => $cat_name, 'category_parent' => $parent) );
}
```

Has anyone ever seen this before? A function coming up as undefined though it appears to be from both the code and Codex documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most probably trying to use [`wp_create_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_category/) on the front end, which will lead to the fatal error. `wp_create_category()` is not available on the front end, only backend.

You should hook your function to at least `admin_init` where `wp_create_category()` is available.

Just a note, looking at the source code, `wp_create_category()` uses [`category_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/category_exists/) which is quite expensive to run on every page load, so you would want to run this once like on a plugin or theme activation hook

Comment: That was it, I was trying to hook it into load-(page) and still getting the error. Thanks!